# How to restore the default keyboard shortcuts in KDE plasma 5.24.5?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, plasma

I deleted the panel and then added a default panel on KDE plasma's desktop. Now the Windows/meta key does not open the application launcher/ start menu.

I restored the default keyboard shortcuts as well as custom keyboard shortcuts but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at so many posts with no solution at all. Here is a simple solution that worked for me.

1. Right-click the KDE icon that you use to bring the start menu.
2. Click on configure application launcher.
3. Go to Keyboard shortcuts tab.
4. Add Alt + F1 as the shortcut and hit apply

I don't know why, but for some reason, this works instantly. No logout, no restart.